# как узнать кратность чисел на python

Tags: python

Как можно найти все числа меньше 1000 кратные 3 и 5 с помощью кода на python

Comment: Т.е. делится ли число на 15?

Comment: Можно сразу на 15 проверять или даже сразу с шагом 15 пробегать, как заметил EOF, либо в лоб: `print([n for n in range(100) if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0])` (если хотите что-то этим сказать)

Comment: Я перепутал вот такая задача

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in range(15, 1000, 15):
    print(x)
```